# with gradle application plugin, how to call the run task with arguments from other task?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have 2 sub-projects:

- project A with the application plugin applied
- project B

I am trying to call the run task from the project A in the project B.

This works fine for me:

```
task aTaskInProjectB(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: ':projectA:run') {
}
```

The problem is when I try to pass arguments to the main class of project A.

Is there anything like:

```
task aTaskInProjectB(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: ':projectA:run') {
  args ['myArgument']
}
```

I tried to run a few examples, however none was related to my use case.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me - maybe someone will find it useful:

project A:

```
run {
  args = project.properties.getOrDefault('projectAArgs', [])
}
```

project B:

```
ext {
  projectAArgs= ['argument1']
}

task aTaskInProjectB(dependsOn: ':projectA:run')
```

Comment: Is this really the canonical way to do this? (looks like a terrible antipattern: communication via a global variable)